# on change of textbox value, check condition on the basis of rails instance variable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my rails application, I have a text-area whose value changes on the basis of checkbox.
text-area

```
<%= f.text_area :sent_to, :class => 'form-control'%>
```

On change of content of this text-area, I want to count the number of comma separated values in the text-area and check it if it exceeds the number stored in the instance variable @org_msg_limit. 
The instance variable have field promo_limit on the basis of which I want to check the number of comma separated values in the text-area. If the value in the text-area exceeds the number in promo_limit than display a alert/message. How to do this?

I tried to make a hidden field to set the value of variable from instance vairable

```
<%= hidden_field "trans_limit", :value => limit.trans_limit.to_i %>
```

Than made a .change function as follows but its not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sent_to').val().change(function() {
            alert("hello");
        var limit = $('#trans_limit').val();
        alert(limit);
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In addition to @ArslanAli's query, do you want to do this on the client side with javascript or use rails validation?

Comment: Try using `keydown` or `keyup` instead of `change`.  Textarea do not respond to `change` event if I am not mistaken. e.g. `$(document).on('keydown', '#sent_to', function(e) { ... });`

Comment: @vee I tried that but still not working

Comment: Could you perhaps reproduce this in https://jsfiddle.net and post your link?

Comment: @vee I tried your updated example in the comment but still not working. In jsfiddle rails code won't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82423/discussion-between-ajeet-khan-and-vee).

Comment: Is your selector correct?  This being a javascript problem, it is possible to extract out the html and javascript and use jsfiddle.  Yes a rails app is not going to work in jsfiddle!